# Sharepoint Online modern site - automatically updated and searchable Employee Directory

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

On a Sharepoint Online modern communication site, how can I build a searchable employee directory that gets its details from the Office 365 active user accounts (and is automatically updated when they change their details or leave/join etc)? Preferably including links to their Delve profile.

All the information I've found online regarding how to do this is either aimed at on premises sites or classic sites.

Answer (score 1):

Now, there is no OOB method to create a People Directory in a modern page in communication site.

There are two methods which we could build our custom People directory:

1. Using Microsoft Graph API to get the information from Azure AD
2. Develope a SPFx Web Part that renders the information coming from Azure AD and in this Web Part we can provide search features.

Comment: just to clarify, are these two separate methods or did you mean use an SPFx web part to get the data from Microsoft Graph API?